# Flash player won't load on subdomains

Tags: flash

I cannot get my flash application to load on any subdomains.

Everything works fine on site.com, but subdomain.site.com will not load the application:

I've got a **crossdomain.xml** file like so:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE cross-domain-policy SYSTEM "/xml/dtds/cross-domain-policy.dtd">
<cross-domain-policy>
  <site-control permitted-cross-domain-policies="all"/>
  <allow-access-from domain="*" to-ports="*" secure="false"/>
  <allow-http-request-headers-from domain="*" headers="*"/>
</cross-domain-policy>
```

Any ideas what is happening here?

### Update

We're connecting to an FMS server using RTMP (Influxis) and recording videos directly there. That's the first and only connection that's made without some kind of interaction by the user. On subdomains, they aren't getting a chance to interact with the application because it just never loads.

### Update 2

Okay, we made progress. The swf and asset urls were being referenced from `app.com` but were being embedded on `subdomain.app.com`. Changing the assets to relative paths `/` fixed the initial issue... only now we don't have access to the cameras or microphones...

Comment: Are you sure that your problem come from **crossdomain.xml** because usually it's not used for **RTMP** connections !

Comment: Thats good to know... I didn't develop the Flash application, I'm just maintaining the site that uses it. The crossdomain.xml file was the first place I looked that I thought I could make a difference without finding a flash developer.

Comment: Can you give us more details may be we can get the real cause of your ptoblem ?

Comment: I will try... one quick though: I pass an image url as a `flashvar` for a backdrop in certain scenarios. Will flash allow images with paths like `app.com` to be loaded into an application embedded via `subdomain.app.com`?

Comment: `app.com` should give authorization to `subdomain.app.com` to load any content from it.

Comment: I updated the question... making progress but have a new problem

Comment: When you are speaking about cams and mics you want to say that your flash do video encoding ?!

Comment: Yes... straight from the RTMP connection to the FMS server

Comment: Verify flash player configuration and authorization to get cams and mics list because this has no relation with the connection to the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That crossdomain.xml looks pretty open to me.  Without knowing exactly what your application is trying to load, it's hard to know what is going on to break it.  Have you tried to run Fiddler, or Firebug Net panel enabled to see if there are any 404's in the traffic when you try to load it?  That might help to isolate the issue.